# Convert mysql varchar to float or epoch time?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a databse that I loaded using python `with time.time()` which results to a time in seconds that looks like 1370449004.766663 and so on.

These are in a column named time that is of type varchar.

How can I convert this column to be able to utilize the `from_unixtime()` command discussed [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql-from-unixtime.php).

When I do this now:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) from table;
```

the output is 0. where time is a varchar column with the output of `time.time` from my python command.

However, my main goal is to convert this column to be noted as a float column so that I can do math on it without having to cast it each time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: float? if you remove the dot it is simply a count of microseonds, no? Then your accuracy will be much better, calculations faster and troubles - less

Answer (score 1):

`unix_timestamp()` takes a date as input.  It doesn't make sense to call it on a `varchar` like `1370449004.766663`.

To convert a `varchar` column to a `float` column, you could:

```
alter table YourTable add FloatColumn float;
update YourTable set FloatColumn= convert(time, float);
```

It's an even better idea to store a date as a `datetime` column:

```
alter table YourTable add DateTimeColumn datetime;
update YourTable set DateTimeColumn = from_unixtime(convert(time, float));
```

Comment: Can you add the semicolons to these lines. New to sql. Thanks

Comment: To help us give useful feedback, be as specific as you can.  Try to reproduce the error on sqlfiddle.com, or at least post the exact error message.